# my reducer say "never" which using selectors cant not detect the state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using the latest versin of react. I want to get state of the current state screen shot, but I get a error that say the type is empty object and reducer is "never", i cant not detect state at all when trying to useSelector, I have put the store into the provider also

ERROR

```
TS2322: Type 'EmptyObject & { session: never; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

index.js

```
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from "./rootReducers";

let token = false
if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
  token = true
}

const initialState = {
    session: {
        isAuthenticated: token,
        user: null
    }
}

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger);

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, 
    // initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(middleware));


type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;

export default store;
```

root-reducer.ts

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import sessionReducer from "./session/reducer";


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    session: sessionReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

session-reducer.ts

```
import { RECEIVED_USER } from "./types";
import { IUser } from './interface';

export interface IAction {
    type: 'RECEIVED_USER'
    payload?: any
}

export type InitialState = {
    isAuthenticated: boolean,
    user: IUser | null
}

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: null
};


const sessionReducer = (state=initialState, action:IAction) => {
    Object.freeze(state);

    switch(action.type) {
        case RECEIVED_USER:
            return {
                ...state, 
                user: {[action.payload.id]: action.payload},
                isAuthenticated: true
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default sessionReducer;
```

profile.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useAppSelector } from '../redux/store';

const Profile: React.FC<any> = () => {

    const user = useAppSelector((state) => state)

    console.log(user)
    return (
        <div>
            {user.email}
        </div>
    )
};

export default Profile;
```

package.json

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.27",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.1",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "json-server": "^0.17.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "json-server -w db.json -p 5000"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving this error

Comment: @Tom - it is in the profile.tsx

Answer (score -1):

create store directly instead of using combineReducers just because combineReducers used **when you having multiple reducers** else it will return an error.

```
const store = createStore(
    sessionReducer, //Add sessionReducer directly
    composeWithDevTools(middleware)
);
```

then you having session object inside initState so, use selector as per below

```
const { user } = useAppSelector((state) => state.session)
```